# Filter a Query Set by Reverse Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

If I have the following:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=150)
```

What argument do I pass to `Project.objects.filter()` to get all Projects that have no associated Assets.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a left outer join like:

```
Project.objects.filter(asset__isnull=True).distinct()
```

Comment: Im getting "cannot resolve keyword 'asset' into field. My code is slightly different since I am using Factories in Test Cases so I'll have to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to take unique Assets into the list. And filter on opposites with tilde ~ using

[class Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/).

```
from django.db.models import Q


Project.objects.filter(~Q(pk__in =Asset.objects.values_list('project', flat=True).distinct()))
```